# Identify movie about spaceship crew exercising with 'gravity body patches'

Tags: story-identification, space

- **What is it?:** A science fiction (TV) movie, or pilot episode.
- **Tell us what it isn't:** It is not Star Trek, Buck Rogers, Battlestar Galactica. I have skimmed lists of science fiction movies from the 70s, 80s and 90s on Wikipedia, but haven't been able to find it.
- **Tell us what made it memorable:** It felt less campy than most sci-fi of the time. The crew of a spaceship exercises using small patches on their bodies simulating gravity/weight. There was a bald villain who was related (brother?) to one of the (female?) characters of the crew. The finale takes places on a barren surface with the villain climbing some metal frame construction.
- **When did you see this film?:** Early 90's on Dutch TV. It was probably broadcast more than once.
- **How old was it?:** Unsure, but it has an 80s (early 90s) vibe.
- **What language was it?:** English.
- **Was it part of a series?:** Probably not (though it could be the pilot of one).
- **What details can I recall?:** Set and costumes were minimalistic. Not very colourful, cool tones (blue). The pace/action was a bit slower.
- **Other details:** The intro might have shown the characters' faces partly as wireframes (or similar effect). The movie probably did not contain any aliens or non-human characters (at least not in appearance).

Comment: That's some good detail and a good question. Well done

Comment: I closed this question as a duplicate. That is not a censure of any sort, just part of our bookkeeping to tie entries together in the database. Congrats on finding your answer! :) As you can see by following the line of linked entries, *Earth Star Voyager* comes up pretty often. I get the impression that many of us had it as an early formative experience. I know I did (although it was probably a decade before I realized it wasn't *Battlestar Galactica*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is [Earth Star Voyager](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0095077/), the pilot of a would-be series, which probably kept it off the radar of several lists of science fiction movies of the 80s and 90s. It eventually popped up as a YouTube suggestion while watching possible candidates. The villain is not completely bald, but has a mohawk-style haircut. Also the finale I described is more in the middle of the movie (since it was broadcast in two parts, this makes sense). The family connection between crew member and villain is there, as are several fitness scenes with the 'patches'. I could even find the intro with the wire-frames faces. I don't think it aged well, though.